# checkbox issue when removing items

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

Im having this issue when checkbox moves up a row when items are removed. How could I ensure checkbox is not moving up or duplicated? because now I have to check if checkbox is duplicated manually which is not an ideal solution.
Here's the code for removing items for reference.

```
Dim n, s   As Long
Dim bSelected As Boolean
Dim Cell, c As Range
Dim rng    As Range: Set rng = Range("A27:H42")
Dim ws     As Worksheet
Dim colItem As Long, sItem As String
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim selectedItems As New Collection
Set SelectedItem = New Collection

For n = 0 To Me.ListboxResult.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListboxResult.Selected(n) Then
        bSelected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next n

If Not bSelected Then
    MsgBox "Please select an item to remove.", vbOKOnly, "Selection Required"
    Exit Sub
End If

For s = s To Me.ListboxResult.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListboxResult.Selected(s) Then
        selectedItems.Add s
    End If
Next s

colItem = 1                                   ' 2nd column in listbox
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("E:E")
With ListboxResult
    For i = .ListCount To 1 Step -1
        If .Selected(i - 1) Then
            sItem = .List(i - 1, colItem)
            Set c = rng.Find(sItem, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                c.EntireRow.Delete
                Set c = Nothing
            Else
                'MsgBox sItem & " not found on sheet", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            .RemoveItem i - 1
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Properties of the checkbox `Don't move and size with cells`

Comment: I did that but it seems that the checkbox can still be moved after I set it to that or do I have to disable design mode first?

Comment: In case CDP wasn't clear, you don't need your collection anymore (see your previous question) nor that first two For-loops. The check if there was anything selected can be moved in the code CDP provided and then move the msgBox part below there. About the checkbox, you can only move the checkbox in designer mode if the properties are set correctly.

Comment: You mean colItem?
and these two for-loop: 
```For n = 0 To Me.ListboxResult.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListboxResult.Selected(n) Then
    ...
```
and

```
For s = s To Me.ListboxResult.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListboxResult.Selected(s) Then
      ...```

Comment: What is `Range("A27:H42")` is it a table ?

Comment: Yeah it's a table with the content based on the userform

Comment: In that case just refresh the table after deleting the listbox items. No need to delete rows on the sheet.

Comment: ok cool thanks.